# Getting Error: Trying to get property of non-object in

Tags: php

I am getting this `Trying to get property of non-object in` at `if ($fetch_size_id->num_rows > 0)` and at `else if ($fetch_size_id->num_rows == 0)`.

Can't figure out what is causing it.
The if conditions don't work as well...

When I `var_dump($fetch_size_id)` I get `bool(false)`.

```
        $fetch_size_id = $conn->query("
            SELECT 
                `sizes`.`size_id`,
                `sizes`.`width`,
                `sizes`.`ratio`,
                `sizes`.`construction`,
                `sizes`.`diameter`
            FROM `sizes` 
            WHERE
                `sizes`.`width` = '".$conn->real_escape_string($row['5'])."'
            AND `sizes`.`ratio` = '".$conn->real_escape_string($row['6'])."'
            AND `sizes`.`construction` = '".$conn->real_escape_string($construction)."'
            AND `sizes`.`diameter` = '".$conn->real_escape_string($row['7'])."
        ");

        if ($fetch_size_id->num_rows > 0) { 
            $fetch_size_id = $fetch_size_id->fetch_object(); 
            $temp_size_id = $fetch_size_id->size_id;

        } else if ($fetch_size_id->num_rows == 0) { 
            //create new

        } else { 
            //error 
        }
```

Am I overlooking something?

Comment: Your query failed, so `$fetch_size_id` is not the result object you expect it to be and therefore it has no property called `num_rows`. Your query fails because you're missing a closing `'` after the condition for diameter.

Comment: @rickdenhaan I've been staring at what was wrong for 10 minutes and couldn't see that. Thanks.

Comment: For future reference, if the result of a call to `$conn->query()` is `false`, that means the query fails. You can then look at `$conn->error` for the error message your database gave.

Answer (score 0):

You are not checking variable `$fetch_size_id`

```
  if (isset ($fetch_size_id){
    if ($fetch_size_id->num_rows) { 
        $fetch_size_id = $fetch_size_id->fetch_object(); 
        $temp_size_id = $fetch_size_id->size_id;
      } else{ 
        //create new
      }
    } else { 
        //error 
    }
```